# Enable saving in GridView row if text changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this GridView in my aspx page. Whenever the user changes any of the data in this grid i need the Save button corresponding to that row to be enabled.

```
<asp:GridView ID="FoodBagItemsGridView" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    DataKeyNames="FoodBagItemId" runat="server" OnDataBound="FoodBagItemsGridView_DataBound"
    OnRowCommand="FoodBagItemsGridView_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Save" Text="Save" CommandName="SaveFoodBagItem" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"RowIndex") %>' Enabled="false" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Delete" Text="Delete" CommandName="DeleteFoodBagItem" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"RowIndex") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure ?');" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="FoodBagItemId" HeaderText="Id" />

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtItemQuantity" Text='<%# Bind("ItemQuantity") %>' OnTextChanged="EnableSaving"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtItemQuantityInput"></asp:TextBox>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtItemName" Text='<%# Bind("ItemName") %>' OnTextChanged="EnableSaving" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtItemNameInput"></asp:TextBox>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Include In Food Bag">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChkBxIncludeInFoodBag" Checked='<%# Bind("IncludeInFoodBag") %>' OnCheckedChanged="EnableSaving" ></asp:CheckBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChkBxIncludeInFoodBag"></asp:CheckBox>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I thought of adding a On Change event for  each of the data columns to fire a C# function "Enable Saving", in this function i would enable the save button for the row in the command argument.

Is there a simpler / more professional way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridView has the [`CurrentCellChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcellchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. you can use it.
Another possible solution could be use [`RowEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`RowLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowleave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events.

Another option (only for windows forms) could be [`RowValidating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating.aspx) Event where you check if `IsCurrentRowDirty` Property is changed

> IsCurrentRowDirty Property Gets a value indicating whether the current row has uncommitted
>   changes.

Comment: I understand that RowValidating is only available in windows forms, is there an alternative for WebForms ?

Comment: You're right, that event is only for win forms. I've update my answer. There isn't that event for web forms :(